# Wordpress CSS changes do not reflect

Tags: css, wordpress, caching

I am working on WP 3.5.1, the latest version with a Duotive Three theme installed in it. Everything was working fine until 2 days back, but from 2 days, whenever I edit my CSS file either through the FTP or the Wordpress Admin, it does not reflect in the browser, either in the website or when I open the CSS file in the browser directly. However, the changes start reflecting a few hours later, I do not know how long exactly. But it frustrates me a lot because I need to wait for a long time to see the changes and check them.
I have tried refreshing the browser with Shift + F5, I deleted browser cache, cookies and even temp files. But still it does not work. Please help.
Note:- I have been working in Wordpress since around 6 years now, built more than 100 websites in Wordpress but this is the first time I am facing this problem. I tried to consult with my network of friends and spent hours googling, many had similar problems but not exactly like mine.

Comment: Do you have a plugin enabled that might be caching the CSS file?

Comment: It could be a problem of the hosting provider. Did you tried to see if in local you have the same problem?

Comment: I had problems with a host six months ago. They were using some heavy caching (Varnish Cache) on PHP and MySQL-database. It would take between 3-5 minutes before I could see changes made. I contacted them, and they made some changes and it got a little better. In the end I got tired and moved the site to another host.

Comment: Use Ctrl + F5 to force you browser to clear cache. If that's not the issue, ask your hosting provider if they have server side caching enabled. If that's the case, you should use something like WAMP or MAMP to dev the theme locally on a staging instance than upload it to your production server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that you might do is to add a version number where the css is called.

If it is called in the head, you can do it like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="youtstylestyles.css?version=1.0" media="all" />
```

This will make the browser refresh.

There is also a variable in the `wp_enqueue_style()` function (if that is how the stylesheet is added) and if you up that it will force a refresh.

Comment: As I said, I had cleared all cache and even deleted temp files and force refreshed the website thousands of times. The biggest problem is that I am working for a client and the client is not ready to provide me the CP so that I can download the database in my local system. But still he wants the CSS changes to be done by me. :) I am also guessing that this is a server side scripting issue. But thanks John, the above solution worked out. I added a version to the CSS and it immediately refreshed. But every time I make changes I have to change the version. Anyways, I will have to take that pain!

Comment: Occasionally I find it helpful to keep the css file open in the browse, in addition to whatever else I'm working on, because I can refresh it and be assured that it's whatever my browser is seeing.

Comment: How in the world would anyone ever figure out where this is called from?  I've seen this same answer in a million places.  No idea where to go to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In your WP Admin GoTo

Appearance -> Theme Options -> Dynamic CSS ->
In this option scroll down you can see **USE** option

Here you need to select **Internal Stylesheet** from drop down menu.